Detect if Nuget uses proxy
I am currently working with the nuget CLI tool in the office and at the homeoffice.
In the office is use the following setting in my global Nuget.config:
<config>
  <add key="https_proxy" value="companyProxy" />
  <add key="http_proxy" value="companyProxy" />
</config>

In the homeoffice I remove those setting but I am getting this error every time:
NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

When I want to access https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json via browser or curl it works.
So my question is, is there another place where a proxy can be configured which I do not see?
I have checked all other .config files which are displayed in "NuGet Config files used:" in the output of the nuget restore and none of them includes a proxy.
Thank you for your answers.

Have you tried using the command line interface?

Yes am just using the CLI
